# Aura can't be deployed using SFDX

Tags: deployment, aura, salesforcedx

I have a package with Lightning Components metadata.

After converting to SFDX format using this command:

`sfdx force:mdapi:convert -r ../src`

the folder structure of the aura components is generated properly.

After trying to deploy it into a scratch org, i'm getting this error:

```
$ sfdx force:source:push -u chris1

ERROR running force:source:push:  Unexpected file found in package directory: /Users/tempflip/mm/payments/payments-sfdx/force-app/main/default/aura/BlackthornTerminal/BlackthornTerminalStyle.css.
```

The CCS file mentioned of course is part of the package, and it can be deployed using the metadata API.

If I delete the `aura` folder from `force-app/main/default`, I can deploy the code into the scratch org using the sames SFDX command.

Maybe this is happening because aura is not supported yet by SFDX? If it is supported, how can I fix this error?

Comment: Is this file BlackthornTerminalStyle.css already in your metadata folder ? Did you create it manually ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your css file does not have the correct name. For a component named `BlackthornTerminal`, it should be `BlackthornTerminal.css`. Try to rename it and push it again.

Comment: thanks for answer! These files are created by the Metadata API when retrieving the package; also, we are using these files to deploy the codebase, and it always goes through. Maybe this is a Metadata API version issue? Also, we are using CumulusCI for retrieving -- maybe it creates some non-standard file format?